# Is there a standard name for the bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Is there a frequently used letter (name) to denote the obvious bijection $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no standard name for the bijection \begin{align} \mathbb R^2 &\to\mathbb C\\ (x,y)&\mapsto x+yi.\end{align}
It is assumed that everyone understands that $\mathbb C$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, so no one ever explicitely writes down this bijection. In fact, I can't even think of a situation where  there would be a need to.

Comment: Well, one may sometimes work in a context where there is a substantial difference between the real structure and the complex structure (like the fact that a differentiable function $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ may not be differentiable $\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$), and be in need to switch between the two.